# Why does this css work in live preview but not once uploaded to a server?

Tags: css, animation, hover, transform

This css seems to work fine in live preview, but when i upload it to the server the drop shadow and image scaling on hover do not work. also on the project pages in live preview there is a black background behind my main image, but doesn't show once uploaded.

```
#carousel {
  background-color: #0C090D;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .artist-about { display: none; }
  #prod-img { width: 50vw; }
}

#prod-img {

  max-width: 100vw;
  background-color: #0C090D;
}

#img-cont {
  background-color: #0C090D;
}

.card {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transform: scale(1.025);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #0C090D;
}
```

I would like to know what the issue is, and why it only gives my problems once uploaded. thank you. 
you can see what my problem currently is by visiting
http://zrwpureart-com.stackstaging.com/

Comment: Your CSS looks fine. This is likely a caching issue, though it is possible there are other styling rules being added to your live website. But given the code you have above, it will work correctly in a production environment.

Comment: thank you! i never would have though about that

Comment: Yes chances are its cache, just clear cache or go to incognito browser and try to ctrl + f5 to hard refresh.